# How to print array index?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to print the array index for some purpose. Can anybody tell me about this ?

Comment: Please accept your previous questions, and explain your question properly.

Comment: In what, PHP or Javascript? Also, *what* array index? All indexes in the array? Sorry, you'll need to provide some more context here.

Comment: How, when, where and why? In PHP or in Javascript? (you tagged both)

Your question is to vague for us to be able to produce a helpful answer.

Answer (score 4):

Get the first index of an elemnt:

```
$array = array(0 => 'blue', 1 => 'red', 2 => 'green', 3 => 'red');
$key = array_search('green', $array); // $key = 2;
echo $key;
```

For all elemnts

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    echo "{$key} => {$value}\n";
}
```

will output

```
0 => blue
1 => red
2 => green
3 => red
```

All keys:

```
echo implode(', ',array_keys($array));
```

will output

```
 0, 1, 2, 3
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you mean with this question but you could try

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r ($arr);
echo "</pre>";
```

that way you'll see your entire array including all the indexes

Answer (score 0):

if you mean the keys of the array:

```
$array = array(0 => 100, "color" => "red");
print_r(array_keys($array));

//result
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => color
)
```

This will provide an array of the keys